# How to make the . button in a calulator

Tags: java, calculator

I'm kinda new to Java and I have been trying to create a calcuator. I have gotten everything to work except the . button, can anyone help me figure out how to do this, I have tried everything that I know, but nothing works

This is the code I got so far:

```
package Java24;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Calculator extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    JPanel row1 = new JPanel();
    JTextField display = new JTextField("0");
    Font font = new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 24);

    JPanel row2 = new JPanel();
    JButton c = new JButton("C");

    JPanel row3 = new JPanel();
    JButton num7 = new JButton("7");
    JButton num8 = new JButton("8");
    JButton num9 = new JButton("9");
    JButton divide = new JButton("/");

    JPanel row4 = new JPanel();
    JButton num4 = new JButton("4");
    JButton num5 = new JButton("5");
    JButton num6 = new JButton("6");
    JButton multiply = new JButton("*");

    JPanel row5 = new JPanel();
    JButton num1 = new JButton("1");
    JButton num2 = new JButton("2");
    JButton num3 = new JButton("3");
    JButton minus = new JButton("-");

    JPanel row6 = new JPanel();
    JButton num0 = new JButton("0");
    JButton dot = new JButton(".");
    JButton equals = new JButton("=");
    JButton plus = new JButton("+");

    public Calculator(){
    super("Calculator");
    setSize(450,350);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(6,1);
    setLayout(layout);

    GridLayout layout1 = new GridLayout(1,1);
    display.setFont(font);
    display.setEnabled(false);
    row1.setLayout(layout1);
    row1.add(display);
    add(row1);

    c.addActionListener(this);
    c.setFont(font);
    row2.setLayout(layout1);
    row2.add(c);
    add(row2);

    num7.setFont(font);
    num8.setFont(font);
    num9.setFont(font);
    divide.setFont(font);
    num7.addActionListener(this);
    num8.addActionListener(this);
    num9.addActionListener(this);
    divide.addActionListener(this);
    GridLayout layout2 = new GridLayout(1,4);
    row3.setLayout(layout2);
    row3.add(num7);
    row3.add(num8);
    row3.add(num9);
    row3.add(divide);
    add(row3);

    num4.setFont(font);
    num5.setFont(font);
    num6.setFont(font);
    multiply.setFont(font);
    num4.addActionListener(this);
    num5.addActionListener(this);
    num6.addActionListener(this);
    multiply.addActionListener(this);
    row4.setLayout(layout2);
    row4.add(num4);
    row4.add(num5);
    row4.add(num6);
    row4.add(multiply);
    add(row4);

    num1.setFont(font);
    num2.setFont(font);
    num3.setFont(font);
    minus.setFont(font);
    num1.addActionListener(this);
    num2.addActionListener(this);
    num3.addActionListener(this);
    minus.addActionListener(this);
    row5.setLayout(layout2);
    row5.add(num1);
    row5.add(num2);
    row5.add(num3);
    row5.add(minus);
    add(row5);

    num0.setFont(font);
    dot.setFont(font);
    equals.setFont(font);
    plus.setFont(font);
    num0.addActionListener(this);
    dot.addActionListener(this);
    equals.addActionListener(this);
    plus.addActionListener(this);
    row6.setLayout(layout2);
    row6.add(num0);
    row6.add(dot);
    row6.add(equals);
    row6.add(plus);
    add(row6);

    setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        String button = e.getActionCommand();
        if(button.equals("C")){
            display.setText("0");
        }
        if(button.equals("7")){
            int lol = Integer.parseInt(display.getText());
            if(lol != 0){
                int num = 7;
                int prevNum = Integer.parseInt(display.getText());
                display.setText("" + prevNum + num);
            }else{
                int num = 7;
                display.setText("" + num);
            }
        }
        if(button.equals("8")){
            int lol = Integer.parseInt(display.getText());
            if(lol != 0){
                int num = 8;
                int prevNum = Integer.parseInt(display.getText());
                display.setText("" + prevNum + num);
            }else{
                int num = 8;
                display.setText("" + num);
            }
        }
        if(button.equals("9")){
            int lol = Integer.parseInt(display.getText());
            if(lol != 0){
                int num = 9;
                int prevNum = Integer.parseInt(display.getText());
                display.setText("" + prevNum + num);
            }else{
                int num = 9;
                display.setText("" + num);
            }
        }
        if(button.equals("4")){
            int lol = Integer.parseInt(display.getText());
            if(lol != 0){
                int num = 4;
                int prevNum = Integer.parseInt(display.getText());
                display.setText("" + prevNum + num);
            }else{
                int num = 4;
                display.setText("" + num);
            }
        }
        if(button.equals("5")){
            int lol = Integer.parseInt(display.getText());
            if(lol != 0){
                int num = 5;
                int prevNum = Integer.parseInt(display.getText());
                display.setText("" + prevNum + num);
            }else{
                int num = 5;
                display.setText("" + num);
            }
        }
        if(button.equals("6")){
            int lol = Integer.parseInt(display.getText());
            if(lol != 0){
                int num = 6;
                int prevNum = Integer.parseInt(display.getText());
                display.setText("" + prevNum + num);
            }else{
                int num = 6;
                display.setText("" + num);
            }
        }
        if(button.equals("1")){
            int lol = Integer.parseInt(display.getText());
            if(lol != 0){
                int num = 1;
                int prevNum = Integer.parseInt(display.getText());
                display.setText("" + prevNum + num);
            }else{
                int num = 1;
                display.setText("" + num);
            }
        }
        if(button.equals("2")){
            int lol = Integer.parseInt(display.getText());
            if(lol != 0){
                int num = 2;
                int prevNum = Integer.parseInt(display.getText());
                display.setText("" + prevNum + num);
            }else{
                int num = 2;
                display.setText("" + num);
            }
        }
        if(button.equals("3")){
            int lol = Integer.parseInt(display.getText());
            if(lol != 0){
                int num = 3;
                int prevNum = Integer.parseInt(display.getText());
                display.setText("" + prevNum + num);
            }else{
                int num = 3;
                display.setText("" + num);
            }
        }
        if(button.equals("0")){
            int lol = Integer.parseInt(display.getText());
            if(lol != 0){
                int num = 0;
                int prevNum = Integer.parseInt(display.getText());
                display.setText("" + prevNum + num);
            }else{
                int num = 0;
                display.setText("" + num);
            }
        }
        if(button.equals("+")){
            plus();
        }
        if(button.equals("-")){
            minus();
        }
        if(button.equals("*")){
            multiply();
        }
        if(button.equals("/")){
            divide();
        }
        if(button.equals("=")){
            if(plusNum != null){
                int secondNum = Integer.parseInt(display.getText());
                int sum = firstNum + secondNum;
                String secondNumber = String.valueOf(secondNum);
                display.setText("" + sum);
                if(plusNum != null){
                    remove(plusNum);
                }
                if(minusNum != null){
                    remove(minusNum);
                }
                if(multiplyNum != null){
                    remove(multiplyNum);
                }
                if(divideNum != null){
                    remove(divideNum);
                }                
                datNum = new JLabel(secondNumber);
                add(datNum);
                }
            if(minusNum != null){
                int secondNum = Integer.parseInt(display.getText());
                int sum = firstNum - secondNum;
                String secondNumber = String.valueOf(secondNum);
                display.setText("" + sum);
                if(plusNum != null){
                    remove(plusNum);
                }
                if(minusNum != null){
                    remove(minusNum);
                }
                if(multiplyNum != null){
                    remove(multiplyNum);
                }
                if(divideNum != null){
                    remove(divideNum);
                }
                datNum = new JLabel(secondNumber);
                add(datNum);
            }
            if(multiplyNum != null){
                int secondNum = Integer.parseInt(display.getText());
                int sum = firstNum * secondNum;
                String secondNumber = String.valueOf(secondNum);
                display.setText("" + sum);
                if(plusNum != null){
                    remove(plusNum);
                }
                if(minusNum != null){
                    remove(minusNum);
                }
                if(multiplyNum != null){
                    remove(multiplyNum);
                }
                if(divideNum != null){
                    remove(divideNum);
                }
                datNum = new JLabel(secondNumber);
                add(datNum);
            }
            if(divideNum != null){
                int secondNum = Integer.parseInt(display.getText());
                int sum = firstNum / secondNum;
                String secondNumber = String.valueOf(secondNum);
                display.setText("" + sum);
                if(plusNum != null){
                    remove(plusNum);
                }
                if(minusNum != null){
                    remove(minusNum);
                }
                if(multiplyNum != null){
                    remove(multiplyNum);
                }
                if(divideNum != null){
                    remove(divideNum);
                }
                datNum = new JLabel(secondNumber);
                add(datNum);
            }
        }
    }

    int firstNum;
    JLabel plusNum;
    JLabel minusNum;
    JLabel multiplyNum;
    JLabel divideNum;

    JLabel datNum;

    void plus(){
        firstNum = Integer.parseInt(display.getText());
        String firstNumber = String.valueOf(firstNum);
        if(minusNum != null){
           minusNum = null;
        }
        if(multiplyNum != null){
           multiplyNum = null;
        }
        if(divideNum != null){
            divideNum = null;
        }
        plusNum = new JLabel(firstNumber);
        add(plusNum);
        display.setText("0");     
    }

    void minus(){
        firstNum = Integer.parseInt(display.getText());
        String firstNumber = String.valueOf(firstNum);
        if(plusNum != null){
            plusNum = null;
        }
        if(multiplyNum != null){
            multiplyNum = null;
        }
        if(divideNum != null){
            divideNum = null;
        }
        minusNum = new JLabel(firstNumber);
        add(minusNum);
        display.setText("0");     
    }

    void multiply(){
        firstNum = Integer.parseInt(display.getText());
        String firstNumber = String.valueOf(firstNum);
        if(plusNum != null){
            plusNum = null;
        }
        if(minusNum != null){
            minusNum = null;
        }
        if(divideNum != null){
            divideNum = null;
        }
        multiplyNum = new JLabel(firstNumber);
        add(multiplyNum);
        display.setText("0");     
    }

    void divide(){
        firstNum = Integer.parseInt(display.getText());
        String firstNumber = String.valueOf(firstNum);
        if(plusNum != null){
            plusNum = null;
        }
        if(minusNum != null){
            minusNum = null;
        }
        if(multiplyNum != null){
            multiplyNum = null;
        }
        divideNum = new JLabel(firstNumber);
        add(divideNum);
        display.setText("0");     
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Calculator calc = new Calculator();
    }
}
```

Comment: Might be useful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself

Comment: Rather than saying you've "tried everything" (which is technically untrue else you'd have tried something that works) - it would be more helpful to describe what you've tried, why you thought it would work and the specific reasons why it didn't.  Dumping your entire codebase isn't going to entire people to wade through it to help you - consider finding an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) instead.

Answer (score 2):

Something along the lines of...

```
if(button.equals(".")){
    if(display.getText().indexOf('.') < 0 ){
        display.setText(display.getText() + ".");
    }else{
        //raise error
    }
}
```

Also make sure you change all others to `Double.parseDouble` from `Integer.parseInt`... make sense?